# An error occurred submitting the question (C++ code)

Tags: support, error-message

I know there are several similar questions on SE but I have found neither a solution nor a reason of my problem there.

---

So I try to post a question which consist of only C++ code and text (see Fig.).

But when I press button [image].

I get the message in the red box [image]

This is my question:

[image]

What is a problem?

Comment: That's a either a server-side 500 error, or a network error between you and the server, both of which are hard for us to diagnose. If you don't have any local network problems, just re-try, I'd say.

Comment: Given that we get tons of C++ questions every day, I'd wager it is not your question content here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I do not have any local network problems. I have been trying it for hour.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, Can I try to post some silly question just for check? Then If it will be posted I will delete it.

Comment: OP managed to post THIS question, after all, showing it's likely not a network issue.

Comment: I mean on SE SO (not meta).

Comment: @J.Steen: network problems can be intermittent.

Comment: @paraxod: There well may be a problem on SO where something is broken, we just can't easily diagnose it. Because there are other C++ questions being posted ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46599873) was posted 3 minutes ago), I doubt it is specificly about C++ code. You could try to post *half* of your question then quickly edit and add the other half (save your text locally in a text editor). If that doesn't work, post the other half, bisect your way to a work-around.

Comment: POSTED. Finally. Should I delete this question?

Comment: BTW. After I pressed the *Post Your Question* button I was requested to pass a CAPTCHA.

Comment: @paraxod: that usually happens when you copy-paste a post. No human can type that fast, so you get checked.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Aye, but for over an hour? Could happen, I guess. I'm pampered with my stable interwebs. =)